# AWS Fargate container does not have access to the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-fargate

Fargate container stuck at PENDING state with a message:

```
CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref 
"docker.io/hello-world": failed to do request
```

1. Fargate container has a public IP address and resides in a public subnet.
2. Route table has a default route 0.0.0.0/0 through IGW.
3. NACL has only default rules.

Meanwhile, I can create an EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet and it will work fine.

VPC terraform config:

```
module "vpc" {
  source                         = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version                        = "3.11.0"
  name                           = "${var.namespace}-vpc"
  cidr                           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs                            = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets                = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets                 = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]
  enable_dns_hostnames           = true
  enable_nat_gateway             = true
  single_nat_gateway             = true
  enable_classiclink_dns_support = true
  enable_classiclink             = true
}
```

Fargate terraform config:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "fg-service" {
  name                 = "${var.namespace}-service"
  cluster              = aws_ecs_cluster.fg-cluster.id
  task_definition      = aws_ecs_task_definition.fg-task.family
  launch_type          = "FARGATE"
  scheduling_strategy  = "REPLICA"
  desired_count        = 1
  force_new_deployment = true

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = var.vpc.public_subnets
    assign_public_ip = true
    security_groups  = [var.sg.fg]
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = module.alb.target_group_arns[0]
    container_name   = "${var.namespace}-container"
    container_port   = 80
  }
}
```

Security group terraform config:

```
module "fg_sg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "~> 4.0"
  name    = "${var.namespace}-sg"
  vpc_id  = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_with_source_security_group_id = [
    {
      rule                     = "http-80-tcp"
      source_security_group_id = module.lb_sg.security_group_id
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is DNS resolution enabled in your VPC?

Comment: Yes, I've added my terraform configuration to the question above

Comment: Does your ECS service security group allow outbound internet access?

Comment: Yes, it has outbound internet access by default, I just added terraform config of sg to the question.

Comment: I don't see any outbound rule for internet access in the security group you have added. Usually this should include all outbound traffic for http(80)/https(443).

Comment: A thought that all outbound traffic in the security group is allowed by default, isn't it?

Comment: It is allowed only if there is an explicit outbound rule for that. You should be able to easily verify the defined rules for a sg using the AWS console/cli.

Comment: Thank you, not it works!